# header.php doesn't evaluate PHP variables before get_header()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a php file with  bunch of php at the top and then:

```
$title2="stevea";   
get_header();
?>

<!--  Display the form  -->

<body>
```

The header file that get_header() pulls in is

```
<?php
/**
 * Header Template
 *
 * Here we setup all logic and XHTML that is required for the header section of all screens.
 *
 * @package WooFramework
 * @subpackage Template
 */
$title="qwerty";
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'charset' ) ); ?>" />

<title><?php echo $title ?> | <?php echo $title2 ?></title>
```

And when the page loads the source shows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<title>qwerty | </title>
```

So the PHP variable defined in header.php ($qwerty) was found and evaluated by the `<title>` line but the PHP variable defined before get_header() is called ($stevea) is not found and evaluated.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: $title2 variable is not use by header page if you use $title2 on header page then it work. because the variable is local scope.

Comment: Yes, but I can't do that because $title2 is actuallycalculated by the php file that calls get_header(). It's not just $title2="stevea" it's something like like

Comment: instead of calculating on template file you can calculate on header file. using various condition checking like whether it is home page or not, whether it is category page or template page

Answer (score 0):

@Samir,

Yes, this is how I solved it.  The variables come from meta data so in header.php I reread them with:

```
$meta = get_post_meta($ID);     
$meta = array_map(function($n) {return $n[0];}, $meta);     
$product_title=$meta['product_title'];
$barcode_number=$meta['barcode_number'];
```

Now I can write:

```
<title><?php echo $product_title ?>  Barcode <?php echo $barcode_number ?></title>
```

and the right data gets plugged in.